# pre-fetch docker image on existing k8s cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a web application which loads a service/pod based on a docker id set in a config map.  If the image is not on the node, k8s nicely pulls the image.  I want to front load the fetching time. Is this possible ? That is, how would I distribute a new docker image to every node in a k8s cluster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a sample of how to pre-pull using a DaemonSet:

https://gist.github.com/itaysk/7bc3e56d69c4d72a549286d98fd557dd

Let me know if that works for you